# angular data isn't showing

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm currently having problems outputing data in angularJS from a JSON.

I'm pulling JSON from SoundCloud to show song titles. Here is my app:

```
(function() {
// define the app
var app = angular.module('PartyPlayer', []);

// create the song lister controller
app.controller('SongListCtrl', 
    function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/13158665.json?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID").success(function(data) {
        $scope.songs = data;
    });

});
})();
```

and I'm trying to add the data here:

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="SongListCtrl as songList">
<div class="small-12 columns">
  <div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li>{{songList.songs.title}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But nothing shows up.  When I `console.log(data.title)` I get the correct result, but not when I go to add it to my controller in the html.  Anyone know the reason why this is happening? Any help would be gratefully appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: {{songList.songs.title}} to {{songs.title}}

Comment: Gosh darnit, that worked... haha stupid mistakes I guess.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You have set a scope variable as songs and referring it in the html markup with songsList.songs

Your actual HTML Markup should be

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="SongListCtrl as songList">
<div class="small-12 columns">
  <div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li>{{songs.title}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```